# How to run a uniswap-interface using yarn

Tags: reactjs, shell, blockchain, yarnpkg

I have cloned `uniswap-interface` from git. I ran the `yarn start` command and received the following output:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn compile-contract-types && react-scripts start
$ yarn compile-external-abi-types && yarn compile-v3-contract-types
$ typechain --target ethers-v5 --out-dir src/abis/types './src/abis/**/*.json'
Successfully generated 2 typings!
$ typechain --target ethers-v5 --out-dir src/types/v3 './node_modules/@uniswap/?(v3-core|v3-periphery)/artifacts/contracts/**/*.json'
'v3-periphery)' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 255.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 255.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 255.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with how your interactive shell (cli) interprets the bit that says `'./node_modules/@uniswap/?(v3-core|v3-periphery)/...'`. Can you tell us where you found that command (the last one, that fails)?

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
./node_modules/@uniswap/?(v3-core|v3-periphery)/artifacts/contracts/**/*.json
```

to

```
./node_modules/@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/**/*.json
```

in the package.json file fixed it for me.